# How to wait for Firestore to find documents and returning result?

Tags: swift, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I am attempting to have my program check for unique usernames. My problem right now is that it will return before completing. I understand since this is async and happening in the background; however, I have attempted using DispatchGroups and semaphores and non of which are working. This is in swift and any help would be appreciated. I am fairly new when it comes to Firestore.

```
func checkUsernames(_ user: String) {
    let docRef = db.collection("userRI").document(user)
    
    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            self.uniqueUser = false
            print("does exist")
        } else {
            self.uniqueUser = true
            print("does not exist \(self.uniqueUser)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

docRef.getDocument() is asynchronous and returns immediate before the query is complete. The callback will be invoked some time later. That means your function will return before `uniqueUser` has a value.

The idea to fix is to consider an escaping callback to pass the value around.

```
func checkUsernames(_ user: String, completion: @escaping (_ uniqueUser: Bool) -> Void) {
    let docRef = db.collection("userRI").document(user)
    
    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            completion(false)
            print("does exist")
        } else {
            completion(true)
            print("does not exist \(self.uniqueUser)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To add to the answer, without being too narrow minded there are other options available such as using Combine publishers, callbacks and notifications. Just thought it would be worth pointing this out.